# Multiple virtual hosts with Apache in live development server, Laravel 9 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-9

I have a dev server that is used by me and a fellow dev, I have set up similar scenarios on live development servers before. The following Apache set up has worked on other Laravel projects, though lower versions.

The set up:
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu)
PHP 8.1.18 (cli)
Laravel 9.19
React 18
Inertia 0.8.1
vite v3.2.6

There are 3 working directories, dir1, dir2 and dir3.  In the apache conf files the following virtual host conf is enabled, {ip} omits the real IP addresses.

Apache virtual hosts file:

```
Listen {ip}:81
Listen {ip}:82

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName {ip}
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir1/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

<Directory /var/www/dir1/public>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost {ip}:81>
    ServerName {ip}:81
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir2/public

<Directory /var/www/dir2/public>
#   Require all granted
   AllowOverride All  
</Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost {ip}:82>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir3/public

<Directory /var/www/dir3/public>
   Require all granted
   AllowOverride All  
</Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The working directory (dir1), serves and presents the application fine, dir2 and dir3 both through the same apache error

```
[Wed May 10 15:06:12.166000 2023] [php:error] [pid 45741] [client {ip}:53093] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:335\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/RegisterErrorViewPaths.php(18): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()\n#1 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(642): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\RegisterErrorViewPaths->__invoke()\n#2 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(623): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths()\n#3 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(554): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderHttpException()\n#4 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(460): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse()\n#5 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(377): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderExceptionResponse()\n#6 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(493): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render()\n#7 /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(138): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->renderException()\n#8 /var/www/dir2/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()\n#9 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/dir2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 335
```

I have ran every cache clear command known to me, including the all singing all dancing php artisan optimize:clear

I've ran composer:update, npm run build, all to continue to get the same error each time.

I have ran this exact same Virtual host set up before in other Laravel 8 projects with even more ports and directories and have copied the exact same structure so the issue lies with the framework itself, however, I can't narrow down the root cause as to why the application will not load on another port

Answer (score 0):

2 things to try here
1- set <Directory /var/www/dir2/public> and <Dirctory /var/www/dir3/public>
Exactly like dir 1 with these parameters

```
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
allow from all
Options +Indexes
```

And

2- Disable SELinux

Run the command:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

and then (to disable it also after rebooting)

```
sed 'SELinux=enforcing/s//SELinux=disabled/' -i /etc/selinux/config
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue, check your Laravel Logs too, keep forgetting about that log and narrowed down the issue.

It was an app config misconfiguration, which php artisan optimize:clear wasn't fixing, the php artisan config:cache command fixed everything